# get src data with HTMLagilitypack

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to catch data from a website useing HtmlAgilityPack. I use this code to **get src** but it returns null.

Html code:

```
<div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">
    <img src="index?option=com_capcha&task=capcha" />
```

C# code:

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@style='margin: auto; text-align: center;']/img[@src]");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the node first, then get the attribute. Do this by using:

```
HtmlNode.GetAttributeValue(attribute,default);
```

it will return attribute value or a default if the attribute is not present.

This will get you the src attribute for each of the nodes in your node collection:

```
foreach(HtmlNode node in nodes1){
    string srcValue = node.GetAttributeValue("src","none");
}
```